# Set button text to updated value when redirected from controller

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a button which has date value. When I click on button, a popup form will open. I will change the value and send the value to controller. In controller, after performing some operations, I am redirecting it to same page where my button is present. I am trying to set value sent from controller on button. But the value is not getting changed. I am using thymeleaf. here's my code.

This is my HTML code. Button and popup form.

```
<button id="appDate" th:value = "${date}"></button>
<div id="popupForm" style="display:none;">
    <form th:action = "@{/getDate}" method="POST">
        <input id = "text" type="text" name = "dateValue"  />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

My jquery code to set button text in input on form.

```
$(function () {
    now = new Date();
    $('#appDate').text(now);
});

$(function () {
    $("#popupForm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $("#appDate").click(function () {
        $("#text").prop('value', $("#appDate").text());
        $("#popupForm").dialog('open');
    });
});
```

My controller Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDate",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getDate(@RequestParam("dateValue") String date,ModelAndView model)
{
    String input = date;
    // other functionality
    model.addObject("date",date);
    return "redirect:profile";
}
```

I want to access the date so that I can set it to button value. Can someone help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RedirectAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html).